# Doxygen: no hyperlinks generated for non-member functions

Tags: c++, doxygen

I'm using Doxygen 1.8.14, in my generated documentation, the brief descriptions of class member functions at the top of each html file corresponding to a class and all mentions of such functions in the same html document point to the full function documentation further down on the page via hyperlinks.

However, this does not happen (both cases) for functions which are not class members.

To me this seems like Doxygen is broken or is there something I'm missing? I believe that according to the documentation this should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doxygen, being derived from JavaDoc to a degree, is somewhat class-centric. As such, documented elements which are not members of a class need to be members of *something* for them to appear in the documentation.

Your choices are to make them members of a documented file (which requires that you document the file they appear within), a documented namespace, or to add them to an existing documentation module/group via `\addtogroup` and similar documentation tools.

This is not necessarily a bad thing. Documentation modules are very useful for separating out related functions/classes. And documenting files and namespaces is good too, so that users can see a list of what is a part of each file or namespace.

Comment: I have already documented the class they appear in (by adding a comment block containing the `@file` tag at the top of the file), so that does not seem to work. Documenting the containing namespace does work, I did not want to document it but maybe I'll just live with that (or try grouping).

Comment: @peter please add an example to your question including the changes to your Doxyfile. It might be that something is not 100% correct in respect to your settings.